# Django subqueries & aggregates

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have three models - `Patient`, `Prescription` and `Medicine`. A `Patient` can have zero or more `Prescription`s and a `Prescription` can have zero or more `Medicine`s. `Medicine` has a `duration` field indicating the days for which the medicine is to be taken.

If we have say, two `Prescription`s with two `Medicine`s each with `duration`s of 15, 15 and 15, 30 respectively, then the *maximum prescription duration* for the 2 `Prescription`s are 15 and 30 respectively. And the *total medication duration* for that `Patient` is 15 + 30 = 45.

Now I want to filter the `Patient` queryset to find all `Patient`s whose *total medication duration* is at least a certain specified value. Following is the code (using **Django 3**) I am trying. But, taking the above example, the *total medication duration* I get is 30, not 45.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef, Max, Sum


class Patient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    # ...


class Prescription(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient,
        related_name="prescriptions"
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    # ...


class Medicine(models.Model):
    prescription = models.ForeignKey(
        Prescription,
        related_name="medicines"
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    duration = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    # ...


def get_patients_with(minimum_medication_duration=365):
    patient_qs = (
        Patient.objects
        .annotate(total_medication_duration=Subquery(
            Prescription.objects
            .filter(patient=OuterRef('pk'))
            .values('patient__pk')
            .annotate(max_prescription_durations=Subquery(
                Medicine.objects
                .filter(prescription=OuterRef('pk'))
                .values('prescription__pk')
                .annotate(max_duration=Max('duration'))
                .values('max_duration')
            ))
            .annotate(total_medication_duration=Sum('max_prescription_durations'))
            .values('total_medication_duration')
        ))
        .filter(total_medication_duration__gte=minimum_medication_duration)
    )
    return patient_qs
```

What am I be missing?